# multiple processes using fork()

Tags: c

I'm using this to set up a process in my main:

```
 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) 
      ChildProcess();
 else 
      ParentProcess();
```

How would I go about setting more processes, say for example x4 of them?

Comment: Functions are awesome.

Comment: I know. But I need to use processes in my assignment.

Comment: You can call fork again in the parent's branch ... EDIT: "functions are awesome" meaning you write a function to fork and store child pid, then call 4x

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the parent process, call `fork()` again to get another child. If you put it in a loop then you're golden.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    pids[i] = fork();
    if (pids[i] == 0) {
        ChildProcess();
        break;
    }
}
```

Make sure the child does not call `fork()`. Only the parent.

Answer (score 1):

There is some ways to do this.

For example:
 1. just repeate your `fork()` for 4 times.
 2. use a loop to call `fork()` for 4 times.
 3. wrapps those into a functions